# I have Set range to Last row and I want to copy it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of range (headers) and for each column I'm trying to copy the cells (headers + 1 row offset) until last row and paste it to another worksheet.

I've tried this:

```
Sub CopyandPaste

Dim Lastrow as Long

Lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set P = Application.InputBox("Code", "CODE", , , , , , 8)

P.Columns(2).offset(1, 0).Select
**From activecell to lastrow copy**
Worksheets("Sheets2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


P.Columns(3).Offset(1,0).Select
**From activecell to lastrow copy**
Worksheets("Sheets2").Range("C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

---

Also, if I do a loop, can you please tell me how I can approach it? Basically the idea is to copy a set range and paste it to a new worksheet with a blank column in between.

Comment: An easy way to do it would be to format you data as a table and then use the  `Listobjects("Table1").DataBodyRange` or use `ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange.find("YourHeader")` if you're just looking for specific headers. Also note that using `.select` is not advised so I'd use `P.colums(2).Offset(1, 0).copy` instead

Comment: Thank you Nick! I was working on it couple of nights ago and I was able to make set range work.

Lastrow = Workbooks(Sample).Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set V = Application.InputBox("Sample", "Sample", , , , , , 8)

i = 1
j = 5
For each cell in V
    V.Columns(i).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, Cells(LastRow1, ActiveCell.Column)).Copy
    Workbooks(Sample).Worksheets(1).Cells(2,j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
i = i + 1
j = j + 2
Next


Do you know how I can combine the P.columns(2).Offset(1,0) with Lastrow?

TIA

Comment: i think an easy way would be to use a loop that uses a condition to check whether your pasting process has reached the last row. I.e. `Do... Until CurrentRow = LastRow`